# How do I count the number of automatic subscription renewals for Google Play Store App at given period of time?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, analytics, subscription

I've got an app published on Google Play which has renewing in-app subscriptions. How do I measure the number of automatic renewals per given period of time for specific subscription and country (e.g. last day for weekly subscriptions in US)?

In iTunes Connect it's relatively simple - there is a number of renewals in "Sales in trends". In Google Play store I don't see any similar metric.

Comment: I've spoke to the support, it seems like there is no way to do it now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about filters but you can get no of renewals by orderId's no after two dots.

Take a look at the randoms [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36739101/9522887)

Order id for all recurrences are returned in orderId field of the INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA JSON field (in V3) with each recurring transaction appended by an integer.

Subscription order numbers

To help you track transactions relating to a given subscription, Google payments provides a base Merchant Order Number for all recurrences of the subscription and denotes each recurring transaction by appending an integer as follows:

> GPA.1234-5678-9012-34567 (base order number)
>
> GPA.1234-5678-9012-34567..0 (first recurrence orderID)
>
> GPA.1234-5678-9012-34567..1 (second recurrence orderID)
>
> GPA.1234-5678-9012-34567..2 (third recurrence orderID) ...

Answer (score -1):

You can check several pages from the Google play console like, Statistics page where you can find all the metrics of you app status.
You can get the installation reports, crashes and ANRs, Revenues, rating and also FCM reports.

You can also download the reports from the 'Report' in left bar. You can download an CSV file also.

You can refer the "Statistics & insights" page in google play console help page.

Thanks.

Comment: That does not answer my question. There is no info on number of renewals there per segments I wanted