# Check Google In App Subscription Renewal Status

Tags: python, django, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

I have to implement Google In App susbscription in my app. In server side, I want to validate subscription status of user. The response of subscription is as follow

```
{
  "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
  "startTimeMillis": long,
  "expiryTimeMillis": long,
  "autoRenewing": boolean,
  "priceCurrencyCode": string,
  "priceAmountMicros": long,
  "countryCode": string,
  "developerPayload": string,
  "paymentState": integer,
  "cancelReason": integer,
  "userCancellationTimeMillis": long,
  "orderId": string
}
```

Google has [api](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get) to validate subscription status. Its response is as follow.

```
{
  "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
  "startTimeMillis": long,
  "expiryTimeMillis": long,
  "autoRenewing": boolean,
  "priceCurrencyCode": string,
  "priceAmountMicros": long,
  "countryCode": string,
  "developerPayload": string,
  "paymentState": integer,
  "cancelReason": integer,
  "userCancellationTimeMillis": long,
  "orderId": string
}
```

I want to check user subscription status by using this API. The question I want to ask how will I know that user subscription has been renewed by this response. If user get subscription for one month and after one month, subscription will be renewed automatically. I have receipt for old subscription in my database and I will be using same OrderId to check subscription status. How will I new that subscription has been renewed for that particular orderId.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but still
You can get no of renewals by orderId's no after two dots.

Take a look at the randoms [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36739101/9522887)

Order id for all recurrences are returned in orderId field of the INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA JSON field (in V3) with each recurring transaction appended by an integer.

Subscription order numbers

To help you track transactions relating to a given subscription, Google payments provides a base Merchant Order Number for all recurrences of the subscription and denotes each recurring transaction by appending an integer as follows:

> GPA.1234-5678-9012-34567 (base order number)
>
> GPA.1234-5678-9012-34567..0 (first recurrence orderID)
>
> GPA.1234-5678-9012-34567..1 (second recurrence orderID)
>
> GPA.1234-5678-9012-34567..2 (third recurrence orderID) ...